# empty array, split method

Tags: java, split

My problem is that the array `ms[ ]` doesn't get values when I do split( );
Why is this happening ?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.");    //change format          
        String msgTime = ft.format(date);
        System.out.println(msgTime);

        String ms[] = msgTime.split(".");
        System.out.println(ms.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is split() function takes regular expression as argument, not a simple string. And "." regular expression means "any symbol".
So you need just escape it.

`String ms[] = msgTime.split("\\.");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you meant to do

```
String ms[] = msgTime.split("\\.");
```

[String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression so you should escape any special characters, such as `.`.

Comment: +1 for an explanation.  I'd give it another +1 for a link to the docs if I could.